# How do I get the indexed columns of a table in SQLite database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, indexing, indices

I have created an index named `MyIndex` for the `MyColumn` column in the `MyTable` table in a SQLite database.

```
CREATE INDEX "MyIndex" ON "MyTable" ("MyColumn")
```

To get a list of all indexes in the database, I can use the following query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = 'index';

----------------
MyIndex
```

However, I also want to get the list of columns that are associated with each index. In my case, the MyIndex index is associated with the MyColumn column.

Is there a way to get this information using a SQL query?"

Comment: You can use the same table, `sqlite_master`, to obtain the index definition, then parse it. See the [`sqlite_master` documentation](https://sqlite.org/schematab.html#interpretation_of_the_schema_table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are looking for this:

```
PRAGMA index_info('MyIndex');
```

You can also get the table indexes using:

```
PRAGMA index_list('MyTable');
```

[More details at this excellent guide](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/)

Comment: Thanks, this works. And I can execute this query from C# like other SQL queries?

Comment: Sure thing, check examples here: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/SQLite.NET/SQLiteClient/Execute/php-sqliteclient-execute-method-examples.html

Comment: Is it a good idea to rely on [`PRAGMA`](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html)? “Specific pragma statements may be removed and others added in future releases of SQLite. There is no guarantee of backwards compatibility.” “No error messages are generated if an unknown pragma is issued. Unknown pragmas are simply ignored. This means if there is a typo in a pragma statement the library does not inform the user of the fact.”

Comment: So, what's the alternative? All sql flavors have their ins and outs. You can only use the tools you are given.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras See my comment on the question. I haven’t written up a proper answer because the question is tagged C#, which I am unfamiliar with.